# Build ReadTheDocs based on a tag insted of a branch

Tags: read-the-docs

I would like to follow the OneFlow branching model. There you have only one branch reflecting the latest state. I can build the docs for it without problems.

But the latest **stable** is identified via a tag. On every new release I would delete the `stable` tag from the previous release and then add it the the latest release again.

It seems to me that ReadTheDocs isn't able to react on the base of tags. Or is there a way?

Sidenote: There is an approach in OneFlow to use an extra branch to represent the latest stable release. But this is a workaround. I would prefer to use tags.